# Setting mysql replication with 5.7

Tags: mysql

We are new to MySQL 5.7. Currently, we are using MySQL 5.5.

Now we want to enable multi-source replication by using MySQL 5.7.

To do this initially, we upgraded to 5.6 and then 5.7 but are stuck on how to set-up MySQL GTID replication.

Can any one will help me in suggesting set-up process for setting replication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 ) on master

stop mysql server on master,

```
set server-id =1
```

enable log-bin=mysql-bin in my.ini, start mysql server

2) on slave

stop mysql server,

`set server-id =2` in my.ini

start mysql server

3) on master create replication user on master with slave IP like below

```
CREATE USER 'repli_user'@'slave_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repli_user'@'slave_IP';
```

4) Go To Master

```
flush tables with read lock;

show master status;
```

(note offset file number and offset position)

```
unlock tables;
```

5) On slave

```
change master to
master_host = 'master_IP',
master_user = 'repli_user',
master_password= 'password',
master_log_file = 'mysql-bin.<file-number>',
master_log_pos = offset-pos;
```

6) on slave

```
start slave;
```

show slave status;
You should get "Waiting for master to send event" as slave status;